# An idea for approaching Brocard's problem ($n!+1=m^2$)

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization

When I first discovered this problem, I rewrote $n!+1=m^2$ like this:
$$n!=m^2-1$$
which can be rewritten like this:
$$n!=(m+1)(m-1)$$

From this, I've gathered the following:

- Because n! must contain a factor of 2 to satisfy the equation (smallest possible $n$ is $4$), $(m+1)(m-1)$ must be even; $m$ must be odd to satisfy this.
- Only one of either $(m+1)$ or $(m-1)$ can be divided by 2 to a power of more than one; the other one can be divided by 2, but to no greater power.
- Because prime factors greater than 2 can only occur once between 3 consecutive numbers, and because statement 2 implies that $(m+1)$ and $(m-1)$ have a GCF of 2, $\frac{m+1}{2}$ and $\frac{m-1}{2}$ must be coprime.

These statements hold true for all currently known solutions:
$$4!=5^2-1=4*6=6*4=(2*3)*(2^2)$$
$$5!=11^2-1=10*12=(2*5)*(2^2*3)$$
$$7!=71^2-1=70*72=(2*5*7)*(2^3*3^2)$$

So, is this information at all useful to solving/helping get around Brocard's problem?

Comment: They are fine observations, but a generally useful principle is that if short and simple observations are all that are necessary to solve something, it wouldn't have been open for 152 years.

Comment: Just one thing, (m-1)/2 and (m+1)/2 are coprime because one of them is the other plus 1, that's all.