# How many solutions does this equation have in integers? If they're finite, what are they?

Tags: number-theory

$m!+1=n^2$; $m,n$ positive integers.
I've tried bringing the $1$ to the other side and using the difference of squares, but it seems like an endless analysis, is there a shorter way to solve it?

Comment: Welcome. Generally, taking residues modulo $k$ for some (several) good choice(s) of $k$ helps in solving these equations. You’re expected to show some effort here, but as a freebie I’ll say that taking residues modulo $n>1$ ($n=1$ clearly has no solutions) yields that, if $m\ge n$, the equation has no solutions, so without loss of generality you should consider the equation when $0<m<n$ and $n>1$.

Comment: This is [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem).  See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2618103/an-idea-for-approaching-brocards-problem-n1-m2) as an example and the comments. For the only known solutions see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A085692).